# Find the open-circuit voltage ratio of the following two-port network

Tags: circuit-analysis

This is the circuit:[image: Provided circuit]

Here's what I have done:

- I converted the part before the input of the two-port network (1 capacitor and 2 resistors) into another two-port network and derived the transmission parameters:
  $$[T_1]=\begin{bmatrix}1+\frac{1}{sCR}&-(R+\frac{2}{sC})\\\\\frac{1}{R}&2\end{bmatrix}$$
- I also converted the hybrid parameters of the second two-port to transmission:
  $$[T_2]=\begin{bmatrix}0&0 \\\\ 0&\frac{-1}{a}\end{bmatrix}$$
- As the two-ports are cascaded with each other, the transmission paramaters for the overall network is:
  $$[T]=[T_1][T_2]=\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{a}(R+\frac{2}{sC})\\\\0&\frac{-2}{a}\end{bmatrix}$$
- Notice that \$T_{11}\$ is the inverse of what needed to be found, therefore:
  $$\frac{U_2}{U_1}\mid_{I_2=0} = \frac{1}{T_{11}} = \frac{1}{0} = \infty$$

I'm not sure if my answer is valid. If not, please tell me where I got wrong. Thank you.